# Custom app keyboard shortcuts: different commands with the same name

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, system-settings, software, design

I've created some custom keyboard shortcuts for Sketch within system preferences:

[image]

I'd like to create some additional shortcuts, but what do I do when the commands have the same name within the dropdowns? e.g. there are multiple commands called 'Left' depending on which dropdown you use, see one here:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can spell out the exact "path" to the menu item in question using the  "->" separator when you enter a value for the "Menu Title" in System Preferences. So, in your case, instead of "Left," you'd enter "Arrange->Align->Left" (without quotes) as the menu command in System Preferences.

[Source](https://www.macstories.net/mac/make-keyboard-shortcuts-for-two-menu-items-with-the-same-name/#:%7E:text=Make%20Keyboard%20Shortcuts%20for%20Two%20Menu%20Items%20with%20the%20Same%20Name,-By%20TJ%20Luoma&text=OS%20X%20has%20an%20easy,and%20then%20%E2%80%9CApp%20Shortcuts%E2%80%9D.)